Find $a + b$, provided $Y=a\bar{X} + b\bar{X}^2, E(Y) = {1 \over p^2}$ where $X \sim \text{Geo}(p), X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are simple samples from X.
The question asks you to select one of the choices:
A) -1
B) 0
C) 1
D) 2
I understand the answer till the calculation of E(Y),
$$
E(Y)={a \over p} + {b(n+1)-bp \over np^2} = {1 \over p^2}
$$
But then it transforms the equation to
$$
{na-b \over np}+{b(n+1) \over np^2}={1 \over p^2}
$$
and derives
$$
\begin{cases}
na-b=0 \\
{b(n+1) \over n}=1
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
a={1 \over n + 1} \\
b={n \over n + 1}
\end{cases}
\implies
a + b = 1
$$
Why is this transformation needed? Is this a technique with a name? Why don't just set $a=0$ in the first equation?

Not following.  Why can you simply declare that $a=0$?  If you set $b=0$ you get a different result, for example.

Should say, the quantifiers are very unclear here.  I gather that the top equation is meant to hold for all $p$ simultaneously?

I think setting $a = 0$ has the same effect as setting $na - b = 0$, once $a$ has been set, the value of $b$ will change accordingly to satisfy the equation? But setting $a = 0$ doesn't yield $a+b=1$, so I think there might be some "rules" when solving these kinds of equations.

A slightly easier transformation (clearing the denominators) is to $nap+b(n+1)-bp=n$ and thus $(na-b)p +  b(n+1)=n$.  If this is true for all $n,p$ then you  need $(na-b)p$ to be constant as $p$ changes leading to $na-b=0$ and so $b(n+1)=n$  and thus their results.

A short cut might be that if the original equation is true for all positive integer $n$ and all $p\in (0,1]$ then you might choose $n=1,p=1$ and immediately get $a+2b-b=1$.

Nobody is setting $na-b$ to $0$.  That equality follows by clearing the denominators and noting that you then get a linear polynomial in $p$ which equals a constant.  That implies that the coefficient of $p$ must be $0$.

But, really, the quantifier confusion should be resolved.    I am guessing that the given data is meant to hold for a fixed $n$ and all $p$, because that leads to the official result.  Nothing in the problem statement suggests that my guess is correct.

I would call this matching polynomial coefficients though Wikipedia calls it equating coefficients

Yeah, I think the easiest way to understand it for me is: If you multiply $p^2$ at both side, you get $f(p)=1$, indicating $f'(p)=0$. Never thought I'd be tested in this way, combining differentiation with probability. Thanks everybody.

The trick here is that the equation needs to hold for all $p\in(0,1)$. Multiply the equation by $p^2$ will lead to a linear polynomial in $p$. The coefficient for $p$, i.e., the slope, has to be zero so that the equation can hold for multiple $p$ values.
